HangMan RL with DQN
I am trying to implement the DQN algorithm using the "stable_baselines3" library, but I am encountering difficulties because the model starts to spam the same cicle of letters at every episode, and I cannot understand why. The environment is custom; I wrote it myself, so there might be errors. Could you help me, or at least let me know if the environment has been written correctly?
import gym
from gym import spaces
import numpy as np

class HangmanEnv(gym.Env):
    def __init__(self, words, render_mode=None):
        super(HangmanEnv, self).__init__()
        self.words = words
        self.current_word = None
        self.guessed_letters = None
        self.max_attempts = 6
        self.attempts_left = self.max_attempts
        self.render_mode = render_mode
        
        # Define action and observation space
        self.action_space = spaces.Discrete(26)  # 26 letters
        self.observation_space = spaces.MultiBinary(26)  # 26 lettere, 0 o 1 per ognuna

    def reset(self):
        self.current_word = np.random.choice(self.words)
        self.guessed_letters = []
        self.attempts_left = self.max_attempts
        return self._get_observation()

    def step(self, action):
        letter = chr(action + ord('a'))
        reward=0.0
        if letter in self.guessed_letters:
            reward += -5.0
        else:
            self.guessed_letters.append(letter)
            if letter in self.current_word:
                reward += 1.0
            else:
                self.attempts_left -= 1
                reward += -1.0

        done = self.attempts_left <= 0 or all(c in self.guessed_letters for c in self.current_word)
        obs = self._get_observation()
        info = {}

        return obs, reward, done, info

    def _get_observation(self):
        obs = np.zeros(26, dtype=np.float32)
        for letter in self.guessed_letters:
            obs[ord(letter) - ord('a')] = 1.0
        return obs

    def render(self, mode='human'):
        word_display = ''.join([letter if letter in self.guesses else '_' for letter in self.word])
        print(f"Word: {word_display}")
        print(f"Guesses: {', '.join(self.guesses)}")
        print(f"Remaining Attempts: {self.remaining_attempts}")


here is the application of the algorithm:
# train_dqn.py
import gym
from stable_baselines3 import DQN
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv
from stable_baselines3.common.evaluation import evaluate_policy

def main():
    words = ["aiuole", "amichevole", "rabarbaro", "penna","madre","padre"]
    env = DummyVecEnv([lambda: HangmanEnv(words)])  # DummyVecEnv è necessario per la compatibilità con Stable-Baselines3
    
    # Crea il modello DQN
    model = DQN(
        "MlpPolicy",
        env,
        verbose=1,
        learning_rate=1e-3,
        buffer_size=50000,
        batch_size=32,
        gamma=0.99,
        exploration_fraction=0.1,
        exploration_final_eps=0.01,
        train_freq=4,
        target_update_interval=1000
    )
    
#addestramento modello
    model.learn(total_timesteps=50000)

    # Salva il modello
    model.save("hangman_dqn_model")

    # Carica il modello (se necessario per il test)
    # model = DQN.load("hangman_dqn_model", env=env)

    # Valuta il modello
    mean_reward, std_reward = evaluate_policy(model, env, n_eval_episodes=100, return_episode_rewards=False)
    
    print(f"Mean Reward: {mean_reward:.2f} ± {std_reward:.2f}")

    test_word = ["padre"]
    env_test = DummyVecEnv([lambda: HangmanEnv(test_word)])

    # Esegui il test finale per 3 episodi
    num_episodes = 3
    for episode in range(num_episodes):
        obs = env_test.reset()
        done = False
        step_count = 0
        print(f"\nEpisode {episode + 1}")
        while not done:
            action, _states = model.predict(obs, deterministic=True)
            # Estrai l'azione intera dall'array
            action = int(action[0])  # Estrai l'azione come un intero
            obs, reward, done, info = env_test.step([action])  # Mantieni l'azione in una lista
            env_test.render()  # Renderizza l'ambiente
            print(f"Action: {chr(action + ord('a'))}, Reward: {reward}")
            step_count += 1
            if done:
                print(f"Episode {episode + 1} finished in {step_count} steps")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


I tried to use the already implemented model from baselines. but it does work at all.

Please provide a verbal description of your environment, you state and action space. If possible, try to cut down your code to a more minimal example where you still see the problem.
